# How to calculate daily 52-weeks high/low in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe with typical OHLC values. I want to calculate daily 52 weeks high/low (or other time range) from it and put the result into a dataframe, so that I can track the daily movement of all record high/low.

For example, if the time range is just 3-day, the 3-day high/low would be:
(3-Day High: Maximum 'High' value in the last 3 days)

```
Out[21]: 
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  3-Day-High 3-Day-Low 
Date                                                       
2015-07-01  273.6  273.6  273.6  273.6         0       273.6     273.6
2015-07-02  276.0  276.0  267.0  268.6  15808300       276.0     267.0
2015-07-03  268.8  269.0  256.6  259.8  20255200       276.0     256.6
2015-07-06  261.0  261.8  223.0  235.0  53285100       276.0     223.0
2015-07-07  237.2  237.8  218.4  222.0  38001700       269.0     218.4
2015-07-08  207.0  219.4  196.0  203.4  48558100       261.8     196.0
2015-07-09  207.4  233.8  204.2  233.6  37835900       237.8     196.0
2015-07-10  235.4  244.8  233.8  239.2  23299900       244.8     196.0
```

Is there any simple way to do it and how? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`rolling_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html) and [`rolling_min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_min.html):

```
>>> df["3-Day-High"] = pd.rolling_max(df.High, window=3, min_periods=1)
>>> df["3-Day-Low"] = pd.rolling_min(df.Low, window=3, min_periods=1)
>>> df
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  3-Day-High  3-Day-Low
Date                                                                   
2015-07-01  273.6  273.6  273.6  273.6         0       273.6      273.6
2015-07-02  276.0  276.0  267.0  268.6  15808300       276.0      267.0
2015-07-03  268.8  269.0  256.6  259.8  20255200       276.0      256.6
2015-07-06  261.0  261.8  223.0  235.0  53285100       276.0      223.0
2015-07-07  237.2  237.8  218.4  222.0  38001700       269.0      218.4
2015-07-08  207.0  219.4  196.0  203.4  48558100       261.8      196.0
2015-07-09  207.4  233.8  204.2  233.6  37835900       237.8      196.0
2015-07-10  235.4  244.8  233.8  239.2  23299900       244.8      196.0
```

Note that in agreement with your example, this uses the last three *recorded days*, regardless of the size of any gap between those rows (such as between 07-03 and 07-06).

Answer (score 4):

The above method has been replaced in the latest versions of the python
Use this instead:
Series.rolling(min_periods=1, window=252, center=False).max()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
three_days=df.index[-3:]
maxHigh=max(df['High'][three_days])
minLow=min(df['Low'][three_days])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
last_working_days = 252
Year_min = df[:-last_working_days].Low.min()
Year_max = df[:-last_working_days].High.max()
```