# Iterate through EOD .csv's to create a historical running high, low in each file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, quandl

I'm new to python, but am falling in love with it as my understanding gets better. That being said I've managed to piece together a script to dump the Quandl WIKI EOD database into CSV's for each respective stock. which I've included below (Python 2.7):

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

#this ignores the first symbol in tickers.txt, add a header!
symbols_list = list(pd.read_csv('tickers.txt', index_col=0).T)
print symbols_list

df = {}
for ticker in symbols_list:
    stock = str("WIKI/" + ticker + ".11")
    #print stock
    print str(ticker + ".csv")
    df[ticker] = Quandl.get(stock, authtoken="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", trim_start="2016-01-01")
    df[ticker].to_csv(str(ticker + ".csv"))
```

My next goal is to create a historical running high and low column for each stock csv. This would make it easy to create a historical "gas gauge" for the stock market similar to the ones on http://www.finviz.com/. The new high/new low gauge is extremely useful. When 2000+ stocks make a new low and only a few make a new high, it's easy to gauge just how hard a sell off is.

So far I've managed to iterate through each .csv in my working folder and keep a tally of each new high / new low. My hang up is on the proper way to enter this information into each csv as new columns. The EOD CSV's have ['Date', 'Adj. Close'] for headers in each, and am I looking to add   ['High', 'Low'].

My code so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csv = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.csv')]
print csv
for i in csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    print df
    j=0
    k=0
    for i in df['Adj. Close']: #for each value in adj close
        if j==0:
            j=i
            k=i

        elif i>j:
            j=i #high

        elif i<k:
            k=i #low

        print j,k #print high & low
```

I really appreciate your help guys!
All of the code snippets and answered questions have made learning python so much more enjoyable.

Here's the output of the script so far:

```
['A.csv', 'AA.csv']
            Adj. Close
Date                  
2016-01-04       40.69
2016-01-05       40.55
2016-01-06       40.73
2016-01-07       39.00
2016-01-08       38.59
2016-01-11       37.94
2016-01-12       38.19
2016-01-13       36.86
2016-01-14       37.61
2016-01-15       37.11
2016-01-19       37.20
2016-01-20       37.26
2016-01-21       37.23
2016-01-22       37.98
40.69 40.69
40.69 40.55
40.73 40.55
40.73 39.0
40.73 38.59
40.73 37.94
40.73 37.94
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
40.73 36.86
            Adj. Close
Date                  
2016-01-04        9.71
2016-01-05        9.27
2016-01-06        8.61
2016-01-07        8.27
2016-01-08        8.07
2016-01-11        8.00
2016-01-12        7.28
2016-01-13        7.13
2016-01-14        7.24
2016-01-15        6.90
2016-01-19        6.74
2016-01-20        6.74
2016-01-21        7.09
2016-01-22        6.87
9.71 9.71
9.71 9.27
9.71 8.61
9.71 8.27
9.71 8.07
9.71 8.0
9.71 7.28
9.71 7.13
9.71 7.13
9.71 6.9
9.71 6.74
9.71 6.74
9.71 6.74
9.71 6.74
```

This code worked beautifully:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csv = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.csv')]
print csv
for i in csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    #print df
    df['High'] = pd.rolling_max(df['Adj. Close'], window=df.shape[0], min_periods=1)
    df['Low'] = pd.rolling_min(df['Adj. Close'], window=df.shape[0], min_periods=1)
    #print df

    g = os.path.normcase(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), i)) #os.getcwd()
    print 'full path =', g
    with open(g , "w") as f:
        df.to_csv(f)
```

Now I'll see about creating a historical list of each day's new high/new low

Comment: Can you add sample of `df`?

Comment: And what are your inputs? `print df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use length of `df` - [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) as `window` of [`rolling_min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_min.html) and [`rolling_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html):

```
print df
          Date  Adj. Close
0   2016-01-04        9.71
1   2016-01-05        9.27
2   2016-01-06        8.61
3   2016-01-07        8.27
4   2016-01-08        8.07
5   2016-01-11        8.00
6   2016-01-12        7.28
7   2016-01-13        7.13
8   2016-01-14        7.24
9   2016-01-15        6.90
10  2016-01-19        6.74
11  2016-01-20        6.74
12  2016-01-21        7.09
13  2016-01-22        6.87

df['high'] = pd.rolling_max(df['Adj. Close'], window=df.shape[0], min_periods=1)
df['low'] = pd.rolling_min(df['Adj. Close'], window=df.shape[0], min_periods=1)
print df
          Date  Adj. Close  high   low
0   2016-01-04        9.71  9.71  9.71
1   2016-01-05        9.27  9.71  9.27
2   2016-01-06        8.61  9.71  8.61
3   2016-01-07        8.27  9.71  8.27
4   2016-01-08        8.07  9.71  8.07
5   2016-01-11        8.00  9.71  8.00
6   2016-01-12        7.28  9.71  7.28
7   2016-01-13        7.13  9.71  7.13
8   2016-01-14        7.24  9.71  7.13
9   2016-01-15        6.90  9.71  6.90
10  2016-01-19        6.74  9.71  6.74
11  2016-01-20        6.74  9.71  6.74
12  2016-01-21        7.09  9.71  6.74
13  2016-01-22        6.87  9.71  6.74
```

Comment: Oh Hell Yeah! I ran into the rolling_min/max earlier today, but didn't think to set the window size like that. Thanks man! Yupsiree was right, I just got discouraged by the window. I might make my final version available on github, because this gas gauge is so helpful.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need pandas rollingmax and rollingmin functions! :-)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html

Comment: Right! I saw a nice example from DSM wich I plan on using on top of a non-windowed high/low: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978132/how-to-calculate-daily-52-weeks-high-low-in-pandas

Comment: I may end up using just the rollingmax/min but the trick with that is setting the window size. I'll be running this script on all 3000+ tickers and I have a feeling that choosing the right window for all of them might be hard. I could just make the window huge...